# Ionic Serve error - "Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(es5BrowserSupport)."

Tags: python, node.js, ionic-framework

I am unable to start the frontend server using Ionic. I have tried to install dependencies and numerous methods to run the frontend of my application. I finally get this error:

```
> ng run app:serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100

> Node.js version v17.1.0 detected.

> Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.

> Warning: This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications
locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

> Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or
computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in
websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disable-host-check" if that's the
case.

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(es5BrowserSupport).

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Can anyone provide a method to for setting up Ionic with correct package versions from scratch or provide a better solution?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what this has to do with python; but please clarify how you've set up your ionic project as well as the configuration/code.

Comment: > nvm install 12.20.1 (downgraded due to v17 providing issues)
> npm install -g cordova
> npm install -g ionic
> npm install -g @angular/cli
> npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
> npm install --save-dev node-sass
> cd ../frontend
> ionic repair
> ionic serve

Answer (score 0):

Remove `es5BrowserSupport: True` from angular.json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).